# Tableview And MBProgressHUD not loading objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

So i have this piece of code in my TVC

```
-(void)getCats {
    [HUD showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^{
        catArray = [menuPost getCategories];
    } completionBlock:^{
        if(catArray == nil){
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"Hubo un problema intente mas tarde" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        }
    }];
}
```

i placed some break points and i noticed that i doesn't execute the method right away it jumps to

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return catArray.count;
}
```

so the problem is that since it skips this line of code(below) the numberOfRows is 0 and this method returns an NSMutableArray after making a post it wouldn't display the objects

```
catArray = [menuPost getCategories];
```

Comment: refresh tableview @Cesar Mtz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is fine , `you are not refresh your table`

```
-(void)getCats {
[HUD showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^{
    catArray = [menuPost getCategories];
} completionBlock:^{
    if(catArray == nil){
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"Hubo un problema intente mas tarde" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

  // if your array count ==0 , hidden the table
   [yourtableviewname setHidden:YES];

    }
   else
   {
      // if your array count !=0 , open the table, and reload/refresh the table
     [yourtableviewname setHidden:NO];
    [yourtableviewname reloadData];
  }
}];
}
```